# MYSQL combine order by with group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, mysql-5.7

i need help with a mysql query.
I went through all the previous discussions about ORDER BY & GROUP BY combined and i understand the concept that the grouping is executed before the sorting so the sorting will not work as expected.
This said i cannot manage to adapt my query to using any of the examples provided due to my limited experience with sql.
Could somebody with more experience please point me in the right direction?
I have a collection of products linked to a datafeed table.
I need to search the product table by keyword and return the cheapest product for each datafeed.
There is the possibility of multiple products with the same low price and I need to return only one per each datafeed.

This is what i have until now:

```
select p.*, m.*, d.* from datafeeds as d,  
( 
SELECT   * 
FROM     products AS p
WHERE    1=1
AND (match(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women' in boolean mode)) 
AND p.is_custom = 0
ORDER BY merchant_name, 
display_price
)  AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta as m on p.mykey = m.mykey 
WHERE p.datafeed_id = d.id 
AND (match(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women' in boolean mode)) 
AND p.is_custom = 0 
GROUP BY d.merchant_name 
ORDER BY p.display_price asc limit 50
```

This returns one product for each datafeed but obviously is not the cheapest since the grouping is executed before the sorting

Thanks a lot for your help!

SAMPLE DATA:
https://wtools.io/paste-code/J3b

Comment: Sample data and expected output as text would be useful.

Comment: Also please fix your formatting so that we may read the entire query without having to scroll.

Comment: are you sure  mysql 5.7 allow the use of group by without aggregation function and mixed  explicit and implicit join ??

Comment: formatted the query and added sample data code (external too long to be posted here)
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I found a way to do it using INNER JOIN

I'm posting it as an answer in case anybody needs it

```
SELECT     p.*
FROM       products AS p
INNER JOIN
           (
                    SELECT   p.datafeed_id,
                             Min(p.display_price) AS minprice
                    FROM     products             AS p,
                             datafeeds            AS d
                    WHERE    p.datafeed_id = d.id
                    AND      (MATCH(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2"' IN boolean mode))
                    AND      p.is_custom = 0
                    GROUP BY p.datafeed_id ) AS p2
ON         (
                      p.display_price = p2.minprice
           AND        p.datafeed_id = p2.datafeed_id)
WHERE      (
                      MATCH(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2"' IN boolean mode))
AND        p.is_custom = 0
GROUP BY   p.datafeed_id
LIMIT      50
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have exact table and data to test my query but as per your requirement I think if you try like this, should give the required output.

`select p.*, m.*, d.* from datafeeds as d,  ( 
                         SELECT   *,min(productPrice)  productPrice 
                         FROM     products AS p
                         WHERE    1=1
                          and (match(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women' in boolean mode)) and p.is_custom = 0
group by p.name,min(productPrice)
                         ORDER BY merchant_name, 
                                  display_price)  as p 
left outer join meta as m on p.mykey = m.mykey where p.datafeed_id = d.id and (match(p.name) against ('+saucony +"ride iso 2" -women' in boolean mode)) and p.is_custom = 0 
group by d.merchant_name,productPrice
 order by p.display_price asc limit 50`

Comment: thanks but there are a couple of problems

SELECT   *,min(productPrice)  productPrice

Unknown column 'productPrice' in 'field list' -> i think you meant:

SELECT   *,min(p.display_price)  productPrice

if i correct that i still get another error:

Invalid use of group function